# iphone settings bunde: psmultivaluespecifier in a psmultivaluespecifier?

Tags: iphone, application-settings

I'm trying to modify a setting in my settings.bundle to behave like Settings->General->International->Region Format. Here you can select "Chinese", and a new list appears where the user can select "China", "Hong Kong SAR China", "Singapore" ect...

Is this possible in my settings.bundle, or is this "apple-only"? I've tried to add a psmultivaluespecifier inside a psmultivaluespecifier, but without any luck. I've also looked at PSChildPaneSpecifier, but from what it looks like, this will allow the user to select more then one value, which is not suitable.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to do it - PSMultiValueSpecifier allows only to choose between different values (of any type), and it doesn't allow to go further to subvalues.

Comment: ok, i suspected that aswell, but its nice to get another's opinion.. Thanks!